# Silhouette score for Jaccard distance

Tags: python, binary-data, euclidean-distance

I'm working on a kmeans functionality for a uni assignment. We need to run euclidean clustering on one set of data and then Jaccard on the other. We need to explore a few different models to evaluate the number of clusters and for the Euclidean it was quite straight forward using *sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score*, but this does not give the option to use Jaccard distance.

As such I was wondering if anyone has an idea of how to calculate it for Jaccard distance? I have managed to create a matrix for all the distances to each other. I also used the Elbow method in the Euclidean distance, would that be a valid method for Jaccard as well?

Comment: As far as I remember, the elbow method is for choosing the number of clusters in k-means right? It's a sort of hyperparameter selection technique. So elbow method is valid for Jaccard. The silhoutte score should be valid too, but I guess you need to provide your own pre-computed distance matrix for sklearn.

Answer (score 1):

Use metric="precomputed"

```
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score
silhouette_score(dist_matrix, k_means_cluster_ids, metric="precomputed")
```